# Mongo text query matching when it shouldn't

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a meteor application that's using mongodb. I have a collection called `tasks` which has a field called `summary`. I added a text index on summary.

When I run this query:

```
    return Tasks.find(
        { userId: this.userId, $text: { $search: "#"+term } },
        { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
    );
```

I get tasks that contain both `#myterm` as well as `myterm`.

What I want to get, and what it seems that I should get is only the documents that match `#myterm`. It's ignoring the hashtag character.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this running on the client or the server?

Comment: server. it's in a publish

Comment: It looks like it's probably because `#` is a [delimiter token in mongo](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in escaped quotes, like this:

```
return Tasks.find(
        { userId: this.userId, $text: { $search: "\"#"+term+"\"" } },
        { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
);
```

It seems to be a shell convention for special characters.

Comment: MySQL solved this ages ago by adding facilities to auto-escape search values. Does MongoDB have anything similar? I don't know nor do I want to know all the different characters I have to scan for and escape - why doesn't this happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope it will work

```
return Tasks.find(
    { userId: this.userId, "summary": { $regex: "\#term" } },
    { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
);
```

If you want to search in a specfic field than $regex would be a better option. For this there is no need for any kind of indexing.